# How do I update to the last public revision in my repository?

Tags: mercurial

```
o 911e74cd  44 minutes ago master
|
| @  f085ae95  3 minutes ago
| |  Testing 
| |
| o  4431b579  Today at 11:24 
|/   Feature
|
o  4ab195c4  Today at 04:59
```

I am currently on revision `f085ae95` and I would like to use one `hg update` command to get to `4ab195c4`, which is the last ancestor that is on the public branch in the repository.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *`4ab195c4` ... is the first ancestor for my commit that is in the repository*. All listed commits are in the repository; they can't be listed if they're not in the repository. 4ab195c4 is, however, a commit that is an ancestor of both `@`, the current revision, and some invisible revision higher up above the start of the snippet, so you could use `last(ancestors(.) & ancestors(other))` to find it, given the proper `other`.

Comment: 4ab195c4 is a revision that has been committed to master, so if I clone the repository I would get 4ab195c4. f085ae95 and 4431b579 only exist in my local repository.

Comment: Mercurial is *distributed*. There are multiple clones of the repository. All of your commits are in your repository. Some, or all, or even more-than-all, of these commits may also be in some other repository, but *all* of your commits are in *your* clone. It sounds like you might be looking for difference between draft and published commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg log -r "last(public() and ancestors(.))" --template "{node}"` will print out the hash of the last commit on the public branch that is also an ancestor of the current commit. As such you can now chain command calss via:

```
hg update `hg log -r "last(public() and ancestors(.))" --template "{node}"`
```

or

```
hg rebase -s `<commit-you-want-to-rebase>` -d `hg log -r "last(public() and ancestors(.))" --template "{node}"`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can literally do:

`hg update 4431b579`

and that should work.

This will update the files in your working folder to whatever state they had in the referenced changeset.

You could also use:

`hg up -r -2`

to go back 2 revisions from the working folder, which I think would do the same thing.

Comment: These both would work but `hg update 4431b579` requires copy and pasting the revision and `hg up -r -2` requires calculation the number of revisions to the base revision. Ideally I could have a constant command that would do this behavior no matter how deep I was in the commit chain.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what your question is actually asking for? When you wrote "update X" in the question... what did you have in mind for "X"?

Comment: X ideally should be a constant. So whether I'm on f085ae95 or 4431b579 the command will get me to 4ab195c4. For example mercurial uses "." to mean the current commit. If mercurial had an alias like "base" that would be great. Otherwise perhaps chaining two commands together might get me the desired functionality.